# Backing up a Github account

Tags: github, gitlab

Recently I saw a HackerNews post about someone who got locked out of their github without warning and it made me think I should have copies just in case this happens. The obvious solution is just clone all your repos on your PC but that seems wasteful and hard to keep up to date.

I also saw that you can import github project directly into gitlab, this would be the ideal way imo to back it up, having two redundant cloud copies. My question is, does importing into gitlab duplicate the repo, or does it just make a pointer to it that would break if github were to delete my stuff?

Comment: Importing your GitHub project into Gitlab just clones your project.  If you update your GitHub project afterwords then your Gitlab project will not be synchronized with your GitHub project

Comment: @Ramhound I see, is it easy to keep them in sync? Can I just click a button and gitlab and it will go through and update all the repos?

Comment: No; The feature isn’t intense to be used multiple times.  It’s a way to migrate your project to another Git service.  I would imagine it’s trivial to use the same folder for multiple Git repositories.

Comment: On the other hand, you can create multiple accounts: one for valid usage and one for something you think can break their term of service. I just read someone get suspended because he gave his account to a friend and that "friend" uploaded a bot to check github security and his account has been suspended. If you're going to share your creds or doing suspecting activities, create a separate account and keep the code in your local repo in all case.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much of the data you want constantly "in sync". If you're just talking about the repository files (not issues or pull requests), then you can use a [repository mirror](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html). Doing a pull mirror (from GitHub) is a paid feature for private projects, but free for public projects.

As others have mentioned, an import will only "copy" things over once because it's meant for migration.

If you want a regular backup of your full projects (including issues and the rest), then you can likely use the [migration API](https://developer.github.com/v3/migrations/) to grab a copy automatically on a regular schedule.